# what happens when a process tries to open a file

Tags: linux, memory-management, vfs

I've tried to understand how a process opens a file and got realy confused:

1. **One** of the things that I read mentioned that when a process tries to read a file that is saved in the disk, the file is uploaded to the **RAM** and the to the *process virtual memory* - from there the process can access the file and edit it.
2. **The other way** I read said that when a process tries to open a file using the

   ```
   open("\a\b\file.txt",O_RDONLY)
   ```

What happens is that the kernel produces a dentry for each component of the filepath, than it searches the dentry of the file. That dentry points to the file inode. Then A file object is created and a file descriptor is returned from the function. Now in the processes FDT the file descriptor that was returned points to the file object that was created which points to the file dentry which points to the file inode and the inode point both to the superBlock and to the **Disk**. Like this:
***fd -> object file -> dentry ->inode -> superblock & disk***.

So my question is how the process reads the file, from its VM(optin1) or from the Disk using object file(option2)?

Comment: What is a "dentry?"

Comment: http://books.gigatux.nl/mirror/kerneldevelopment/0672327201/ch12lev1sec7.html
read this it explaines what a dentry is

Comment: Oh.  A "Directory Entry."

Comment: The way a file is read exactly is specific to the OS. The second option you're referring to seems more like it has to do with how the file system works, and how files are looked up, whereas option 1 describes more how the kernel fetches data from disk and loads it onto RAM and virtual memory so that it's accessible to the user. You should look up how paging works

Comment: @0x534f53: Linux.

Comment: `What happens is that the kernel produces a dentry for each component of the filepath` - whoa, this is very specific. What about filesystems without directories? What about files that do not exist on a disc, like `/proc` or `/dev` entries? What filesystem exactly are you referencing?

Comment: ext and vfs but this is not the main subject, I just got realy confused because I thought that a process can read a file or data that is saved on the disk only from its virtual memory